# Why does public key login with with ssh but not with x2go?

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm connecting from a Mac OS X system to a Linux server.  I have set up RSA public key access, so I can just type

```
ssh [hostname]
```

and it will connect without a password.

When trying to connect with the x2go remote desktop client, I get an error:

```
kex error : did not find one of algos diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 in list curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 for kex algos
```

My Mac OS X system is pretty old, running Snow Leopard 10.6.8.  The Linux system is fairly up to date.  The version reported by ssh -v is

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
```

I've heard that this kex error can indicate a mismatch of encryption algorithms on the client and server.  But why does ssh succeed where x2go fails?  Can I get x2go to do whatever ssh does to log in successfully?  Part of the problem is that x2go doesn't report the sequence of events (unlike ssh -v), so I'm not sure what exactly it's tried to do.  If there is a way to make it display a detailed log that would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a key exchange algorithm mismatch. (It has nothing to do with "public key login" from your side. They're completely separate stages.)

The problem comes from:

- X2go bundling a poor-quality SSH client library which doesn't even implement the *required* parts of SSH v2 specification (I found an [X2go bug report](http://bugs.x2go.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472) regarding this situation), and
- blindly following instructions from some blogpost (probably "Secure Secure Shell"?) in order to limit the SSH server to a very small subset of key exchange algorithms, none of which are supported by the X2go client library.

Normally, using a library such as libssh for SSH connections is okay – working with library functions is a bit more convenient than juggling `/usr/bin/ssh` commands in background. However, X2go on your system uses a very old version of libssh – it only implements `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`, but not `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1`, even though [RFC 4253 requires both](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-8.1).

(The difference is that "group1" (Oakley Group 2 [sic]) uses 1024-bit DH parameters, which is [no longer secure enough](https://weakdh.org/). Group 14 meanwhile uses 2048-bit parameters.)

---

You said your Linux system is "fairly up to date". When it comes to cryptographic software, that's *not even close* – the latest OpenSSH is 7.1 (your version is 6 years old), the latest OpenSSL is 1.0.2d (your version is 2 years old), and the latest libssh is 0.7.2 (your version is… old).

- So the best solution would be to **install the latest version of libssh**, which supports a wider variety of key exchange algorithms (such as the same `curve25519-sha256@libssh.org`). However, it'll probably require at least OpenSSL 1.0.x for the elliptic curve algorithm support. So if you're stuck with an older Linux distro, this might be troublesome...
- The other method is to **whitelist `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`** in your server's KexAlgorithms list, alongside the currently listed ones. It will result in comparatively weak X2go connections – strong enough against your neighbours, but possibly weak against Three Letter Agencies. Though, you're still using an OpenSSH version from 2009, so it probably doesn't matter to you anyway.

Comment: To clarify, the ancient openssh mentioned above is on the Mac (client machine).  The Linux version is debian 8.1 and sshd reports version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015.  So not the newest version, but not as old as you were thinking.

Comment: Given that, when you say to install the latest version of libssh, do you mean on the server or client machine?  If on the server, will that do anything to improve the compatibility?  If on the client, will x2go know to use it?  I thought the problem appeared because it was using its own bundled library, rather than whatever /usr/bin/ssh is using.

Comment: But libssh _is_ that library. It has nothing to do with /usr/bin/ssh. They both have "ssh" in the name because they're both SSH clients.

Comment: Let me check whether I understand your answer to my original question, before I decide what to do about it:. (1) /usr/bin/ssh uses its own ssh implementation, not libssh; (2) my x2go version uses an old, bundled version of libssh; and (3) these two implementations of the ssh protocol are different in the features they implement.  Is that correct?

Comment: @mfardal: Right. So you need to upgrade the client. (Though I shouldn't have said "bundled" – chances are, it's simply using the distro-provided libssh, but even that is old.) By the way, I found a [bug report](http://bugs.x2go.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472) in X2go's website regarding exactly this situation.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've failed to locate any libssh on the Mac OS X client system.  And I'm inferring from the bug report discussion that libssh is compiled in directly rather than loaded from the system - at least for versions like Mac OS where you download the app instead of building it on your system.  So it doesn't seem to me that installing a newer libssh on the client will solve the x2go problem on its own.

Comment: Ah right, so OS X is the client, not Linux m( ... Maybe x2go-client is available on homebrew then, which is a [compile-from-source](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:development:build-howto-macos:x2goclient) system?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and surprisingly it wasn't related to any of the SSH config files.
SSH with a password works, X2GO doesn't
reason why it failed: I had a complex password, starting with '°' symbol
Changed my password to a simple string to test, et voila: X2GO works
Seems like X2GO's password field doesn't like special characters